# How can I solve an error in build ionic 4 (PWA)?

Tags: ionic4

I have created ionic 4 new project using following command.

```
ionic start myApp tabs
```

Install angular

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project app
```

And build app

```
ionic build --prod
```

at 92%(92% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin) it doesn't work, stop here and and gives attached error!

Can somone adivse?

[image]

I tried to do the same operation with other projects but it doesn't work.

node v 9.8.0

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to install angular, its already part of an Ionic project. Maybe you are confusing things by doing this.

Try doing the steps above but without this line:

```
ng add @angular/pwa --project app
```

Also btw if you are posting errors, please copy paste them in as text. Your error is hard to read and half clipped off - do yourself a favour and make it easy for people to help you.